# How to use tbl_summary() in a summarized table

Tags: r, gtsummary

Consider this situation:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", 
"patient5"), x = c("h,a,a", "i", "i", "i,a,e", "h")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

        id     x
1 patient1 h,a,a
2 patient2     i
3 patient3     i
4 patient4 i,a,e
5 patient5     h
```

If we do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt_summary)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>% 
  select(x) %>% 
  tbl_summary()
```

We get a summary table with N=9!

[image]

But I need something like this done with the `gt_summary` package to have the same format like the other gt_summary tables:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>% 
  select(x) %>%
  count(x) %>% 
  mutate(percent = round(n/nrow(df)*100)) %>% 
  mutate(N_percent = paste0(n,"/", nrow(df), " (",percent,"%)"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  select(x, N = N_percent) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "Summary of x"
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    N = "Count"
  )
```

N should be 5 and not 9 with the corresponding percents:

[image]

The final output should be a gt_summary table looking like this, and I wish to do it with gt_summary:

[image]

Comment: Could you use gt() instead? It could be built to do everything you want here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gtsummary extension function, `gtreg::tbl_listing()`, that creates listings from data frames. You can use it after you prep your data frame for printing (as you did above). Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(gtreg)
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(
  list(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", 
              "patient5"), x = c("h,a,a", "i", "i", "i,a,e", "h")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)


# prep data for a table
tbl <- df %>% 
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>% 
  select(x) %>%
  count(x) %>% 
  mutate(percent = round(n/nrow(df)*100)) %>% 
  mutate(N_percent = paste0(n,"/", nrow(df), " (",percent,"%)"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  select(x, N = N_percent) |> 
  mutate(grouping_var = "x", .before = 1L) |> 
  # create a gtsummary class listing
  tbl_listing(df, group_by = grouping_var) |> 
  # style table with gtusmmary functions to make it look like `tbl_summary()`
  modify_header(
    x ~ "**Characteristic**",
    N ~ "**N = 5**"
  ) |> 
  modify_column_alignment(N, align = "center") |> 
  modify_footnote(N = "n/N (%)")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much. I am aware of this package <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmslEfczYqM>, but I had previously only associated it with adverse events. However, in the end, it serves the same purpose. Thank you for bringing this to my attention

Comment: How can I do it with a grouping column like  `tbl_summary(by = trt,....`

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Can you post another a reprex? if you use the gtsummary tag, i'll see it within a day or two of posting.

Answer (score 1):

Would be interesting to see whether there is a more straightforward approach. For the table body you could achieve your desired result using `tbl_custom_summary`. To get right N in the table header you could use `modify_header` or `modify_table_sytling`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(gtsummary)

my_stats <- function(data, full_data, ...) {
  data |>
    summarise(
      n = n(),
      N = n_distinct(full_data$id),
      p = n / N
    )
}

tbl <- df %>%
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") |>
  tbl_custom_summary(
    include = c("x"),
    stat_fns = everything() ~ my_stats,
    statistic = everything() ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%)"
  )

tbl |> 
  modify_header(
    stat_0 ~ paste0("**N = ", nrow(df), "**")
  ) 

tbl |>
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = "stat_0",
    label = paste0("**N = ", nrow(df), "**")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this very good solution. I think I will go with the `gtreg` package!

Comment: Sure. This is definitely the more flexible approach. For me this is just some sort of practice and learning about what can be achieved via gt/gtsummary. :D