# How to use tbl_listing from gtreg package in grouped gt_summary table

Tags: r, gtsummary, gtreg

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77630989/how-to-use-tbl-summary-in-a-summarized-table/77631916?noredirect=1#comment136871266_77631916) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77635551/gt-summarytbl-stack-issue-tables-are-shifted-when-using-gtregs-tbl-listing).

Now that I managed to do it for simple tables. I would like to do the same (combine grouped gt summary tables). Here is an example:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gtreg)

df <- structure(list(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", 
"patient5"), x = c("h,a,a", "i", "i", "i,a,e", "h")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                -5L))

tbl <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 3), rep("group2", 2))
  ) %>% 
  add_count(group, name = "groupN") %>% 
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(groupN, group, x) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(N = sum(n),
         percent = round(n / groupN * 100, digits = 1),
         N_percent = paste0(n, "/", groupN, " (", percent, "%)")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(x, N_percent) %>% 
  mutate(grouping_var = "group", .before = 1L) %>% 
  gtreg::tbl_listing(df_en, group_by = grouping_var) 

 
show_header_names(tbl1)


df1 <- structure(list(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", 
"patient5"), y = c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

tbl1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 1), rep("group2", 4))
  ) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = group,  # Grouping by 'group'
    type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({min}-{max})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%)"))
tbl1
# Stacking the tables
tbl_combined <- tbl_stack(tbls = list(tbl, tbl1))
tbl_combined
```

The output is:
[image]

I can't manage how to prepare the first table `tbl` to get a stacked grouped table using the `gtreg::tbl_listing()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time you first need a `pivot_wider` to put the group stats in separate columns and the correct renaming for the stats columns and additionally the label column:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gtreg)

tbl <-
  df %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 3), rep("group2", 2))) %>%
  add_count(group, name = "groupN") %>%
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(groupN, group, x) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(
    N = sum(n),
    percent = round(n / groupN * 100, digits = 1),
    N_percent = paste0(n, "/", groupN, " (", percent, "%)")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(group, x, N_percent) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = N_percent) |>
  mutate(grouping_var = "x", .before = 1L) %>%
  select(grouping_var,
    label = x,
    stat_1 = group1, stat_2 = group2
  ) |>
  gtreg::tbl_listing(group_by = grouping_var)

tbl1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 1), rep("group2", 4))) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = group,
    type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
    statistic = list(
      all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({min}-{max})",
      all_categorical() ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%)"
    )
  )

tbl_combined <- tbl_stack(tbls = list(tbl, tbl1)) |>
  modify_header(
    label ~ "**Characteristic**",
    stat_1 ~ "group1, **N = 1**",
    stat_2 ~ "group2, **N = 4**"
  ) |>
  modify_column_alignment(c(stat_1, stat_2), align = "center") |>
  modify_footnote(stat_1 = "n/N (%)", stat_2 = "n/N (%)")

tbl_combined
```

[image]

**EDIT** To add a p-value you could use `add_p()` for the `gtsummary` table. For the `tbl_listing` table add `p.value` column. Then use `modify_table_body` to add the p-value to the grouping row and use `modify_fmt_fun` for the styling.

```
tbl <-
  df %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 3), rep("group2", 2))) %>%
  add_count(group, name = "groupN") %>%
  separate_rows(x, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(groupN, group, x) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "keep") %>%
  mutate(
    N = sum(n),
    percent = round(n / groupN * 100, digits = 1),
    N_percent = paste0(n, "/", groupN, " (", percent, "%)")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(group, x, N_percent) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = N_percent) |>
  mutate(grouping_var = "x", .before = 1L) %>%
  mutate(p.value = NA) |>
  select(grouping_var,
    label = x,
    stat_1 = group1, stat_2 = group2, p.value
  ) |>
  gtreg::tbl_listing(group_by = grouping_var) |>
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x |>
      mutate(p.value = if_else(label == "x", .8, NA))
  ) |>
  modify_fmt_fun(c(p.value) ~ style_pvalue)


tbl1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("group1", 1), rep("group2", 4))) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = group,
    type = all_categorical() ~ "categorical",
    statistic = list(
      all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({min}-{max})",
      all_categorical() ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%)"
    )
  ) |>
  add_p()

tbl_combined <- tbl_stack(tbls = list(tbl, tbl1)) |>
  modify_header(
    label ~ "**Characteristic**",
    stat_1 ~ "group1, **N = 1**",
    stat_2 ~ "group2, **N = 4**"
  ) |>
  modify_column_alignment(c(stat_1, stat_2), align = "center") |>
  modify_footnote(stat_1 = "n/N (%)", stat_2 = "n/N (%)")

tbl_combined
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show me how to add the p.value? I hope it is the last question on this task!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. And thanks for the reminder. Was a bit busy today. See my edit for an approach to the p-values.