# Adjust plot.background margin in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot background is much larger than the plot and I can't figure out how to reduce it. I have hacked a way to bring the title closer to the plot, but there is still a large space below the plot. This causes issues when I use `cowplot` to place a second plot below it, as there is a large space between the two plots.

I have kept the plot background and titles visible to illustrate the problem.

[image: ggplot with issues]

The code to reproduce this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
win_prob <- structure(list(winner = c("draw", "team_a", "team_b"), prob = c(0.1374, 
0.8412, 0.0214), team_name = c("Draw", "BYU", "Stanford")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

# Plot
p1 <- win_prob |>
  # Add a dummy variable for ggplot
  mutate(dummy = "dummy") |>
  # Plot
  ggplot(aes(x = dummy, y = prob, fill = factor(winner, levels=c("team_b", "draw", "team_a")))) +
  geom_col(width = 0.02,
           alpha = 0.50) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(prob*100, 0), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8C1515", "grey", "#002E5D")) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.05,0.0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0.01)) +
  # theme_void() + # commented out so you can see the plot background
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        # plot.background = element_rect(margin = margin(0,0,0,0)), # doesn't look like you can reduce the margin here
        plot.title = element_text(size = 40, margin=margin(0,0,0,0)),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 28, margin=margin(0,0,-100,0))) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.02, y = 0.0, hjust = 0, label = win_prob$team_name[2], size = 8) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.02, y = 1.0, hjust = 1, label = win_prob$team_name[3], size = 8) +
  annotate("text", x = 1.02, y = 0.5, hjust = 0.5, label = "Draw", size = 8) +
  labs(title = "BYU vs Stanford Win Probability",
       subtitle = "based on xG simulation")

p1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible approach to achieve your result. Instead of adding the labels using `annotate` I add them as top axis labels and pass a vector to set `hjust` for the axis text, which is a bit hacky. Also I use the default bar width to remove the empty space. Instead, if you want a "smaller" bar width then reduce the height of your chart which should also work when glueing to a second plot using `cowplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

win_prob |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = prob, y = "dummy",
    fill = factor(winner, levels = c("team_b", "draw", "team_a"))
  )) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, .6, 0, .6), guide = "none") +
  geom_col(
    width = 0.9,
    alpha = 0.40
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = paste0(round(prob * 100, 0), "%")
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(0, .5, 1),
    labels = c(win_prob$team_name[2], "Draw", win_prob$team_name[3]),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(0, 1),
    position = "top"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8C1515", "grey", "#002E5D")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = c(0, .5, 1), size = 40),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 40, margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 28, margin = margin(0, 0, 40, 0)),
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "BYU vs Stanford Win Probability",
    subtitle = "based on xG simulation",
    y = NULL, x = NULL
  )

ggsave("foo.png", height = 8, width = 16, units = "cm", scale = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: funny but I tried 1 hour the similar approach!: Yours look definitely better! :-) stefan may  I draw your attention to the comment of mine to your answer. Maybe you have an idea. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637648/how-to-use-tbl-listing-from-gtreg-package-in-grouped-gt-summary-table/77637722#77637722>